Parallel planes
The question is: Find all $a$ and $b$ so that the plane $ax+by+20z=5$ is parallel to $2x+3y+9z=0$.
My answer is the following : a parallel plane will have a colinear normal vector to $<2,3,9>$ therefore we get $a=\frac{40}{9}$ and $b=\frac{20}{3}$. Now should I conclude
$$<a,b,c>=<\frac{40}{9}k,\frac{20}{3}k,20k>$$ to complete my solution ?

they specify 20, not 20 k,

We can clarify this by starting with the normal vector of the plane $2x+3y+9z = 0$ which is $\vec{N_1} = \langle2,3,9\rangle$, and the normal vector of the other plane is: $\vec{N_2} = \langle a,b,20\rangle$. So if the two planes are parallel, we have: $\vec{N_1} \parallel \vec{N_2}$. This means there is a real number $k$ such that: $2 = ak, 3 = bk, 9 = 20k\implies k = \dfrac{9}{20} , a = \dfrac{2}{k}=\dfrac{40}{9}, b = \dfrac{3}{k} = \dfrac{20}{3}$. In looking at your solution, the $k$ shouldn't be there in the last line because $k = \dfrac{9}{20}$ which is fixed. Your answer suggested that there are infinitely many solutions and each solution corresponds to a value of $k$. This is not true because there is only one solution $(a,b) = \left(\dfrac{40}{9}, \dfrac{20}{3}\right)$.
